# How to reload page on new Heroku deploy (using node.js)

Tags: node.js, express, heroku

I have a website running on a node.js (via express) server that's hosted on Heroku. Currently if I'm on the website and I deploy a new build, my webpage will not automatically refresh once the deploy is built. I have to manually refresh the page.

How can I make any pages that are open reload automatically when a new deploy is built?

Answer (score 0):

The client would need to get data from the server on the current app version or start time.

```
{
  "version": "1.1.0",
  "start_time": 1510548486047
}
```

An API endpoint like `GET /api/v1/status` polled with AJAX or a websocket message could be sent out on connection to return the data. [Socket.IO](https://socket.io/) is probably the easiest to get started with as it takes care of the client side.

The client side javascript can then decide on what criteria in the response warrants a page reload.

There's a [lengthier answer](https://medium.com/@the1mills/hot-reloading-with-react-requirejs-7b2aa6cb06e1) if you want to hot reload javascript in particular.